# How to store only date and only time in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to store only date and only time in the table using SQL Server 2008.

**Example** My try

```
create table dt( sl int, dateonly date, timeonly time);

insert into dt values(1,11-08-2014,'12:04:00');
```

**Error**:

```
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date
```

**Expected Result**:

```
sl   dateonly   timeonly
------------------------
1   11-08-2014  12:04:00
```

Comment: Use quotes around 11-08-2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `'`

```
INSERT INTO dt VALUES (1,'11-08-2014','12:04:00');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
create table dt( sl int, dateonly date, timeonly time);

insert into dt values(1,'20140811','12:04:00');
```

It's your date string that is in error (well it should be string but isn't)

Please avoid using dd-mm-yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy, in sql server the safest of all formats is YYYYMMDD (no delimiters)

by the way, you might regret not having datetime as one field.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable assistance.